# Компонент для боковой навигации на странице

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, каким компонентом можно реализовать окно программы такого вида:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вам вот прямо сразу компонент, это ж не Delphi.

В WPF в основном делается руками из существующих контролов. Для вашего случая вполне подойдёт `TabControl`. Возможно, достаточно установить [`TabStripPlacement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Если нет, придётся подрихтовать стили.